# How to remove Open Office spreadsheet duplicates in a column while keeping rows together?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, duplicate

I have a spreadsheet with a list of column data of contacts, first name, last name, address, phone number, email...

I want to remove the duplicate email addresses but the entire row may not have duplicate data just the email column.

I believe this is simple to do in excel. I am using openoffice or excel online. Excel online does not have the duplicate function available and the monthly version of excel I need win7 or above I'm using vista.

How can I remove the duplicates from 1 column keeping the row that are left together?

The user may have registered multiple times using say different street addresses but always using the same email address. I want to remove any duplicate email addresses and their entire rows.

So I'm really looking for duplicates in a specific column not duplicates in all the columns.

Another example, I could have hundreds of people with the first name John. I don't want that column to have the duplicates removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since duplication routines typically retain the first value in a duplicate set, you will want to start by sorting your data so that records with ambiguous values will have the more relevant records (aka *rows*) toward the top of the record set. If a *Date Created* or *Date Modified* column is available, this would be a good point to sort by in a descending order.

To *show* a set of rows with unique values in a single column, first select that column and choose Data ► Filter ► Autofilter. Use the column filter's dropdown to choose *Standard Filter*. The *Field name* and *Condition* should already be set so set the *Value* to *Not Empty*. Next click <kbd>More Options</kbd> and put a checkmark beside *No duplication*. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and you should be showing a record set with unique values from the column filtered on. As mentioned, precedence is given to the first rows in the case of duplicate values.

If you want to show the duplicates in preparation to culling them out by deleting the rows, you will need a *helper column*. In an unused column to the right, put this formula into the second row.

`=AND(COUNTIF(B$1:B1; B2))    ◄ assumes that the email address are in column B`

Fill the formula down to the extents of your data. You should receive a series of TRUE and FALSE values where FALSE is unique and TRUE are duplicates. You can now use Data ► Filter ► Autofilter on that *helper column* and filter for TRUE. Use Edit ► Delete cells (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) to delete all of the visible rows and remove the filter. You will be left with a data set of unique email addresses.